# Cannot get swagger UI from deployed to the k8s claster my API

Tags: asp.net, kubernetes, swagger

I enabled Swagger in my project like this:

```
app.UseSwagger();
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
 {
   string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
   c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API");

 });
```

But after deploying my app to the k8s claster, I can't get swagger/index.html page. How i can get it?

I tried to change SwaggerEndpoint, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Hey, could you maybe add your kubernetes Mainfests (service, ingress). It is hard to get advice without this. What kind of response you get when requesting the endpoint? Does your Container answer or an ingress controller (like nginx)? If you are building your Container and running it, does it work then (without k8s)?